# Perform full outer join in mysql

Tags: mysql, join

I already know i can do outer join in MySQL using `union`.
I also check this one.
[Full Outer Join in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql)

But i want to do something like this and I don't know how can I achieve this using union.

I have db table `user_count` as follow.

```
+-------------+-----------+---------+-------+
| meb_id      | left_id   |right_id |active |    
+-------------+-----------+---------+-------+
| 1001        | (NULL)    | (NULL)  |  1    | 
| 1002        | 1001      | 0       |  0    | 
| 1003        | 0         | 1001    |  0    |
| 1004        | 1001      | 0       |  0    |
| 1004        | 1002      | 0       |  0    |
+-------------+-----------+---------+-------+
```

I have queries as follow.

```
    SELECT left_id, COUNT(left_id) AS left_count FROM `user_count` GROUP BY left_id 

    SELECT right_id, COUNT(right_id) AS right_count FROM `user_count` GROUP BY right_id;

SELECT left_id AS meb_id, COUNT(left_id) AS active_left_count FROM `user_count` WHERE active = 1 GROUP BY left_id;

SELECT right_id AS meb_id, COUNT(right_id) AS active_right_count FROM `user_count` WHERE active = 1 GROUP BY right_id;
```

I want to preform outer join or union so my result will be like this

```
+-------------+-----------+------------+------------+--------------+
| meb_id      |left_count |right_count |active_left |active_right  | 
+-------------+-----------+------------+------------+--------------+
| (NULL)      | 0         | 0          |  0         | 0            |
| 0           | 1         | 3          |  0         | 0            |
| 1001        | 2         | 1          |  0         | 0            | 
| 1002        | 1         | 0          |  0         | 0            |
| 1003        | 0         | 0          |  0         | 0            | 
+-------------+-----------+------------+------------+--------------+
```

How can i do this. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your result makes no sense for me. Why does 1001 have 2 right counts, not 1 ? What is with the 0 meb_id ? and null ? You need to give a formula, some logic, not letting us figure what you want

Comment: @Cosmin Sry actually its 1. By mistake I wrote 2.

I am going to edit this.

hope you now understand it.

Comment: @Cosmin 
Actually there is no formula. I only want count of left_id and right_id group by particular column. As you seen in result table I want count of all left and right id with and without active condition.

Comment: why `1004` is not included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select 
    a.meb_id
    ,sum(case when a.meb_id = b.left_id then 1 else 0 end) left_count
    ,sum(case when a.meb_id = b.right_id then 1 else 0 end) right_count 
    ,sum(case when a.meb_id = b.left_id and active = 1 then 1 else 0 end) active_left  
    ,sum(case when a.meb_id = b.right_id and active = 1 then 1 else 0 end) active_right 
from (
    select meb_id from user_count union
    select left_id from user_count union
    select right_id from user_count
) a
cross join user_count b
group by a.meb_id
order by a.meb_id
```

**Demo**
[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0560b/2)